# Put months on MajorGrid and days on MinorGrid (Range bar chart)

Tags: c#, charts

I have this gantt chart :

[image: Chart image]

I want to display months on MajorGrid and days on MinorGrid, I try to change interval but nothing has changed

[image]
[image]

**EDIT :** What I want is something like this :

[image]

Comment: The IntervalType looks good. Can you try to set the Intervals to `1` ?

Comment: @TaW I set it to 1, the result more lines and no values appear like what I wanted

Comment: Of course you get more lines for the MinorGrid, that is for I=1 you get one line per day. What do you want??

Comment: @TaW I want for exemple in the majorgrid (March) in the minorgrid (1,2,3,...)

Comment: This is exactly what you will get. But: The Grids are __only about lines, not text or labels__! Also note that in my 1st comment I meant `AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 1` and `AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;` not `AxisY.Interval = 1;`

Comment: @TaW I tried as you said , I want values in majorgrid and minorgrid if it is possible (see EDIT in my question )

Comment: This is nice but atm I don't see how to get that without customlabels or owner-drawing it. I'll give it a try a little later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two rows of customlabels like this:

```
ay.LabelStyle.Angle = 0;
ay.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
DateTime d1 = DateTime.FromOADate(ay.Minimum);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.FromOADate(ay.Maximum);
int dc = (int)(d2 - d1).TotalDays;
//double dspace = d2.ToOADate() - d1.ToOADate();  // we need a suitable number later (*)
dspace = 10;    // seems to work better when zooming in..
for (int i = 0; i < dc; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = d1.AddDays(i);
    double dd = dt.ToOADate();
    CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
    cl.Text = dt.Day + "";
    cl.FromPosition = dd - dspace;  //(*)
    cl.ToPosition = dd + dspace;   //(*)
    cl.RowIndex = 0;              // 1st row of labels

    ay.CustomLabels.Add(cl);

    if (dt.Day == 1)  // place month name at the 1st day
    {
        cl = new CustomLabel();
        string month = d1.AddDays(i).ToString("MMMM");
        cl.Text = month;
        cl.FromPosition = dd - dspace;  //(*)
        cl.ToPosition = dd + dspace;   //(*)
        cl.RowIndex = 1;              // 2nd row
        ay.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
    }
}
```

where `Axis ay = ca.AxisY;` and `var ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];`.

Result:

[image]

The yellow rectangle was painted in the PrePaint event. Example:

```
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Series s = chart1.Series[0];
    if (s.Points.Count <= 0) return;
    Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;

    var ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    DateTime d1 = DateTime.FromOADate(ay.Minimum);
    DateTime d2 = DateTime.FromOADate(ay.Maximum);

    int x1 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Minimum);
    int x2 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Maximum);
    int y = (int)ca.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(ca.AxisX.Minimum);
    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(11, 222, 222, 111)))
        g.FillRectangle(b, x1, y, x2 - x1, 60);  // 60 pixels large, calculate what you need!
}
```

I have to admit that I'm underwhelmed. Maybe a (much) more involved paint code would come close to your example..

Comment: thank you for this amazing work, that's what I wanted but when I tried it the number of days are very closer,  I tried to solve this by ` ca.AxisY.ScaleView.Size =20; ` but months names become accumulated!

Comment: The offset for the positions was too large. Always tricky to decide on what to use.. It has to be large enough to hold the label but, as it seems not too large; not sure what the reason is..? I have changed it to (fixed) `10` and it works ok here now..